# EWS nullpointer Exception getExchangeServicePort

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, exchangewebservices

Sometimes when I run this code I get a `NullPointerException`. It doesn't come always. I tried two versions, but there is the same Exception.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
```

Version 1:

```
port = service.getExchangeServicePort();
```

Version 2:

```
port = service.getPort(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages","ExchangeServicePort"),ExchangeServicePortType.class);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.checkOverrideProperties(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1142)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:173)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:96)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createSEIPortInfo(WSServiceDelegate.java:652)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.addSEI(WSServiceDelegate.java:640)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:332)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:297)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
```

Comment: The URL for ExchangeWebservice is defined in an wsdl file

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround with works:

```
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.setServiceClass(ExchangeServicePortType.class);
    factory.setAddress(url);

    port = (ExchangeServicePortType) factory.create();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();

    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```